# Can I create a database instance that appears to be of "localdb" instance, but is really of "MSSQLSERVER"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, localdb

My projects web.config use to reference the following in the default transform

**data source=localhost\{instance_name}**

Now however, I am the only team member still using MSSQL, where as the others have switched to that "localdb".

Now the web.config has **data source=(localdb)\{instance_name}**.

Is there a way I can make this instance in MSSQLSERVER but make it appear as if its of localdb?

I have tried to do this with a mssql alias but I can't seem to get it to work (if it can be done that way at all).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Every developer can have different web.config settings which are never committed to code repo. They are just for you. Why can't you change data source value in your working copy!

Comment: Install LocalDB !

Comment: ErikEJ: I have installed localdb, but it crashes when I attempt to "edit all rows".

Comment: niksofteng: If there is a setting that allows this, I do not know where it is. Perhaps we are using web.config wrong as we all share the same web.config. Can you advise me as to where this setting is?